# Application insights requests table client_Type

Tags: azure-application-insights

In application insights I run the following query against the *requests* table:

```
requests 
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where resultCode contains "401"
| order by timestamp
```

the *client_Type* column contains only *PC* values. The API monitored is called by both PCs and mobile devices (smartphones and PDAs). I need to find out if any failed 401 calls have been made from mobile devices.

I tried googling the possible values and found this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/requests (which is not helpful).
What values in column *client_type* would indicate a mobile device? Are there any other methods to separate between PC and mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46899485) your question?

I assume that you wanna to know the client_Type, such as pc, iphone(ios), mobile phone(android), pad... So maybe the **OS type** can help to divide the clients.

```
requests
 | where client_OS has "microsoft"
```

By the way, according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-context#device-type), it seems only having 2 enum values of client_type: browser or pc？

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately, application insights does not fill _client_os_ column for requests, just for pageViews.Client_type should be a good alternative, but application insights does not fill this field either. Will mark as answered, because my team may have an edge case, but this answer may help others.

Comment: Thank you very much, and hope it will help others.