# Query the logs to find out most used browser versions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

I would like to find out a list of the most used browser versions in our application.

When I view the End-to-end transaction details I am able to see a "Dependency property" named "Browser version":

[image: Example of the Dependency properties in the End-to-end transation screen]

Can that perhaps also be used to query the logs?

For example, I'm trying to use:

```
traces
| where operation_Name == "Dependency"
| extend browserVersion = tostring(customDimensions["Browser version"])
| summarize count() by browserVersion
| order by count_ desc
```

But that returns no results.

I have also seen this question: [Application Insight Analytics - Query Client Browser and Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315818/application-insight-analytics-query-client-browser-and-device/67672492#comment134897389_67672492)

That makes a nice list but leaves out the browser version.

Should I use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks correct, and the issue could be due to the "browser version" property. There might be a possibility of the "Browser version" property isn't being captured in the logs correctly.

To check whether it is being captured properly, I ran below set of queries and was able to retrieve the results as expected within the given timestamp.

```perl
traces
| where operation_Name == "DurableFunctionsHttp"
| extend browserVersion = tostring(customDimensions["Browser version"])
| summarize count() by browserVersion
| order by count_ desc
```

[image]

```perl
traces
| where operation_Name == "DurableFunctionsHttpStartDemo"
| extend properties = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions))
| project properties["Browser Version"]
```

[image]

***Alternatively,*** You can run the below query to extract browser versions from the client agents or client Ip's.

```perl
traces
| where operation_Name == "DurableFunctionsHttpStartDemo"
| extend properties = tostring(customDimensions["Client_ip"])
| summarize count() by "browserversion"
```

[image]

**Note:** Verify the timestamp you are using if the query doesn't return any results. Let's suppose if you specified a timestamp of the previous 24 hours and no operations had taken place during that time period, it will only return zero results instead the exact results.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your suggestions and get no results. By the way, the field "Browser version" is only available when I view the tab "Browser" in the End-to-end tab. What could be the case if it is not captured correctly?

Comment: What are all the properties you can see when you execute traces? @Remi

Comment: "No results found from the last 7 days" :|

Comment: Can you check with last 24 hours?

Comment: Same. Could it be because of the difference with "Customer properties" and "Dependency Properties"

Comment: It might be the reason because custom events work in a different way in few scenarios than dependency properties.

Comment: All browser related property settings comes under dependency telemetry as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/app-insights-metrics). Custom properties means we can get the additional telemetry information of the application insights by providing some custom events but dependency properties means we can only retrieve the telemetry data which has already defined or existed.

Comment: In the screenshots you provide, the browser version is empty. Why is that?

Comment: I did not have many logs related to browser version instead I am getting telemetry data for sdk version of the function app insights.